# How to remove title from DT::datatable when using copy button

Tags: r, datatables, r-markdown, dt

I use DT::datatable in lots of HTML rmarkdown reports that eventually get copied into other documents (e.g., Word, Excel) for final formatting/formatting.  The issue I'm having though is that when I use the "copy" button extension to copy and paste from DT::datatable() into the other document is that it has this annoying title that gets pasted along with the table.

For example, if I use the "copy" button from this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = letters[1:5])

DT::datatable(df, 
              extensions = "Buttons",
              rownames = F, 
              options = list(dom = 'Blfrtip', buttons = 'copy'))
```

I get this:

```
Exported data

x   y
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
```

Is it possible to not have the `Exported data` and blank line below it, and to only have this output when I paste?

```
x   y
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `title = NULL` in the list of lists passed to the `buttons` arguments.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = letters[1:5])

DT::datatable(df, 
              extensions = "Buttons",
              rownames = F, 
              options = list(dom = 'Blfrtip', 
              buttons = list(list(extend = 'copy', title = NULL))
))
```